# How to await a build task in a VS Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

```
let result = await vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.tasks.build');
```

resolves immediately.

How can I await a build task with VS Code API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**I figured it out!** Tasks cannot be awaited from `vscode.tasks.executeTask`, but we can await `vscode.tasks.onDidEndTask` and check if ended task is our task.

```js
async function executeBuildTask(task: vscode.Task) {
    const execution = await vscode.tasks.executeTask(task);

    return new Promise<void>(resolve => {
        let disposable = vscode.tasks.onDidEndTask(e => {
            if (e.execution.task.group === vscode.TaskGroup.Build) {
                disposable.dispose();
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}

async function getBuildTasks() {
    return new Promise<vscode.Task[]>(resolve => {
        vscode.tasks.fetchTasks().then((tasks) => {
            resolve(tasks.filter((task) => task.group === vscode.TaskGroup.Build));
        });
    });
}

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    context.subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.helloWorld', async () => {
        const buildTasks = await getBuildTasks();
        await executeBuildTask(buildTasks[0]);
    }));
}
```

Note that currently there is a [bug #96643](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/96643), which prevents us from doing a comparison of vscode.Task objects: `if (e.execution.task === execution.task) { ... }`

Comment: A simple `if (e.execution === execution)` should work now.

Answer (score 2):

I think this depends on how the main command is executed in the extension.ts

Being new to JS/TS, I may be wrong here, but just trying to help:

make sure the vscode.command.registerCommand is not asyncronous, like below:

```
    context.subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.openSettings', () => {
        return vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.openSettings", "settingsName");
    }));
```

This would be compared to something async, like below:

```
    context.subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.removeHost', async (hostID) => {

        const bigipHosts: Array<string> | undefined = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration().get('extension.hosts');

        const newHosts = Hosts?.filter( item => item != hostID.label)

        await vscode.workspace.getConfiguration().update('f5-fast.hosts', newBigipHosts, vscode.ConfigurationTarget.Global);
        hostsTreeProvider.refresh();
    }));
```

Comment: Hi @Benji, thanks for posting and welcome to SO! Please ignore my previous (now deleted) comment. Unfortunately vscode.commands.executeCommand and vscode.commands.executeTask still resolve immediately, but I figured out a way to wait for a task to end (see answer below). Thank you!